# Replace columns with SQL JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-keys

I have the following two tables

Wishlist

```
id    item    created_by    modified_by
---------------------------------------
1     Lips..  5             6
```

Users

```
id    first_name
----------------
5     Mark
6     Clare
```

I need to replace columns created_by and modified_by with the first_name associated with the ID in those fields.

I'm currently using the following code

```
SELECT wishlist.*, user.first_name FROM wishlist
LEFT JOIN user ON user.id = wishlist.created_by
```

Which returns the following result

```
id    item    created_by    modified_by    first_name
-----------------------------------------------------
1     Lips..  5             6              Mark
```

Which is okay.. I guess - but not what I need.

Ideally, I'd like..

```
id    item    created_by    modified_by
---------------------------------------
1     Lips..  Mark          Clare
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the user table twice, specify the exact columns you want and rename them accordingly:

```
SELECT wishlist.id, wishlist.item, u1.first_name AS created_by, u2.first_name AS modified_by FROM wishlist
LEFT JOIN user AS u1 ON u1.id = wishlist.created_by
LEFT JOIN user AS u2 ON u2.id = wishlist.modified_by
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SELECT w.id,w.item, u1.first_name as created_by    , u2.first_name as modified_by
 FROM wishlist w
LEFT JOIN user u1 ON u1.id = wishlist.created_by
LEFT JOIN user u2 ON u2.id = wishlist.modified_by
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
select w.id,
(select First_name from Users 
where id=w.created_by) as created_by,

(select First_name from Users 
where id=w.modified_by) as modified_by

 from WhiteList w
```